# Conservation of momentum in system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

If I consider earth car and man to be a system
[image]
Then why car doesn't move

Comment: It does. A very, very, very, very, very small amount.

Comment: If let's take it to be cycle of same mass then why it doesn't move with same velocity of man in opposite direction

Comment: Because the Earth is also part of this system. You're only exerting force on the Earth - and that only causes an incredibly tiny change in momentum.

Answer (score -2):

Earth has a huge mass and hence it's velocity tends to 0